# How to construct a lucene search query with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am new to Lucene.net ,Here I would like to know how to make a lucene search query almost like an sql query .Lemme give more..

I have set of parameter values,Let assume like a stored procedure has set of parameters .Now I want to build a query with all this parameters.

```
        searchParams.UseLast = Convert.ToBoolean(base.Arguments["UseLast"]);
        searchParams.LastEditedFrom= Convert.ToDateTime(base.Arguments["LastEditedFrom"]);
        searchParams.LastEditedTo = Convert.ToDateTime(base.Arguments["LastEditedTo"]);
        searchParams.Reviewed = Convert.ToBoolean(base.Arguments["Reviewed"]);
        searchParams.Approved = Convert.ToBoolean(base.Arguments["Approved"]);
        searchParams.Include = Convert.ToBoolean(base.Arguments["Include"]);
        searchParams.IsVisibleToUser = Convert.ToBoolean(base.Arguments["IsVisibleToUser"]);
        searchParams.IsEntry = Convert.ToBoolean(base.Arguments["IsEntry"]);
        searchParams.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(base.Arguments["UserId"]);

        IEnumerable Categories = base.Arguments["Categories"] as IEnumerable;
        IEnumerable Departments = base.Arguments["Departments"] as IEnumerable;

        String mQuery = "How to construct it ....!!!" // Need help in this 

        var query = queryParser.Parse(mQuery);
        indexSearcher.Search(query, collector);
```

Here I want to fetch all records from lucene index which has the value for all the above fields.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear what you are using `searchParams` for, however in general you may construct your query string (`mQuery`) in this cases with any of the features of the Lucene query syntax.  Here is a link to the documentation for Lucene.Net version 4.8 [Query Parser Syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package_description).

In general, when multiple words are listed in the query they are treated with a logical OR but doc matches that contain all terms are ranked higher than docs with only one term.  So for example `white dog` would match docs containing `white dog` or `white` or `dog`.  You can put `and` in the statement if you only want docs that match all the terms so for example you could say `small and white and dog` if you only want docs that contain all three terms.

To specify the specific field to search you list the field name followed by a colon.  So for example you can search `UserId:ron and Categories:dogs`.  There is much more to the Lucene query syntax but hopefully that will get you started.  For more details see the Lucene query syntax doc I referred to.